# SCSS ampersand not working when trying to make modifiers for class names

Tags: css, sass

I'm not sure why this is working.. if I put the following it works fine:

```
.popup--bookmark {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px 35px 15px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 220px;
  top: 11px;
}
```

but if i try to break it up for BEM purposes like so, it doesn't work:

```
.popup {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px 35px 15px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;

  &--bookmark {
    left: 220px;
    top: 11px;
  }
}
```

Usage is straight forward like so:

```
<div className="popup--bookmark">
```

What am I doing wrong?  According to this [article](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/) it should work.  Quote from the article:

```
// Touching the ampersand works well with modifier classes.

.btn {
  &-primary {}
  &-secondary {}
}
Compiled CSS:

.btn-primary {}
.btn-secondary {}
```

Comment: both code are different, the second one will apply only top/left to your element

Comment: @TemaniAfif i'm sorry can you clarify what you mean please? I really want the second code to apply to the "popup--bookmark" class, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: the SASS code you wrote will not generate the the CSS code you are showing

Comment: As Temani says, what you have will give the CSS `.popup--bookmark { left: 220px, top: 11px }` It doesn't inherit the parent styles.

Comment: "It doesn't inherit the parent styles" ah okay that makes sense then... thank you both

Comment: @user1189352 you want to use `@extend` for your case.